# Should I block Wordpress archive pages from search engines?

Tags: seo, wordpress, robots.txt, duplicate-content, google-index

I use WordPress and `/sample-post/` URLs for my posts and `/yyyy/mm/` for the archives.

Google has indexed the site fully.

Since the archives currently display full posts I've thought that I shouldn't let Google index the archive pages because they contain the full posts and that will be duplicate content. Thus my robots.txt contains:

```
Disallow: /2009/
Disallow: /2010/
Disallow: /2011/
Disallow: /2012/
Disallow: /2013/
Disallow: /2014/
Disallow: /2015/
```

Do you think this is good practice or would it harm my rankings and/or reachability?

Comment: Good post, just to be clear, do you mean block everything but categories? The thing that brought this problem to my attention was doing Google image search and it showed 4 of same image, from tag/archive, page, post and home! It's on home as part of a slider (featured posts). So what would be benefit of category over pages and posts only? Or do you mean mix or all 3? I also use Yoast but very new to this.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you need to avoid duplicate content on your Wordpress site. Wordpress often generates duplicate content between categories, archives and tags.

In order to fix this issue you can block URLs of archives in *robots.txt* but the best option is to put `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">` on archives pages to avoid getting these URLs indexed by Google.

To do this, you can download [Wordpress SEO plugin from Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/). When plugin is installed, you have an option to put this meta wherever you want (on archives pages, on tags pages, on categories pages...). You can go then to the menu of plugin: *SEO => Titles and metas*.

In my opinion, best pratices for SEO are to put this meta on archives and tags pages and let Google crawl categories pages. I always have avoided duplicate content on Wordpress site like this.

Comment: I noticed however than dispite noindex, nofollow, Google sometimes still index those pages so I decided to put those pages to robots.txt. I wrote blog post about : https://www.vladopandzic.com/search-engine-optimization-seo/block-indexing-wordpress-date-arhives-pages/